# DLL на Delphi. вызов из С++ /CLR

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, x86-64

Имеется DLL написанная на Delphi, которая экспортирует функцию вида:

```
myFunc(param1: PChar; param2: PChar; var param3: PCar): integer;
```

То есть, три парметра типа `PChar`, один из них в виде переменной (`var`).

Нужно: из модуля (тоже DLL), написанного на C++ /CLR передать туда три параметра и увидеть как изменился переменный параметр `param3`.

В общем, с загрузкой DLL, получением адреса функции вопросов нет. Другие функции, где нет переменного параметра вызываются нормально.

Если эту заковыристую функцию вызывать как обычно, то при изменении этого параметра, основное приложение крашится (его исходников у меня нет). Понимаю, что нужен маршалинг данного параметра, с которым пока ничего не получается. MSDN читал два дня, но решение не пришло. Добился только вызова функции без краша приложения, но последний параметр не менялся после вызова.

Может кто сталкивался с подобным и может подсказать решение?

Comment: Главный вопрос в таких случаях - кто ответственен за распределение и удаление памяти, на который указывает (будет указывать) `param3`.

Comment: Я ответственен. :) Возможности лезть в основное приложение нет. Править функцию на Delphi крайне нежелательно. Надо как-то все организовать из сочиняемой DLL на C++. DLL на Delphi, после отработки этой функции, никакие параметры больше не нужны, ее можно (да и нужно) выгружать.

Comment: Так, попробую сформулировать по-другому. Когда вызывается `myFunc`, туда передается `param3`, который указывает на уже распределенную память, или ожидается, что память будет распределена кодом Delphi?

Comment: var означает pointer to. Т.е. это будет указатель на PChar, он же PPChar, или как там в плюсах правильно пишется. И раз не указано соглашение о  вызове - то это `fastcall`, что нужно явно указать вместо обычного для плюсов `stdcall`.

Answer (score 2):

В старых версиях Delphi (до 2009), тип `PChar` обозначал указатель на строку ANSI символов и был псевдонимом для типа `PAnsiChar` аналог сишного `char*`. В новых версиях - это указатель на строку юникодных символов и является псевдонимом для типа `PWideChar` (`wchar_t*`). Для начала определитесь, какой тип используется у Вас. Если Вы используете dll, откомпилированную под Win64, то там используется уже `PWideChar`

Третий параметр в функцию передается по ссылке. Это значит, что указатель может изменяться внутри функции. Как выделять и освобождать память, выделенную в функции - опять таки смотрите в документацию к dll

В функции не указано соглашение о вызове. Это значит, что используется соглашение `register` (`__fastcall`). Более того, для платформы Win64 - это единственно возможное соглашение.

Итого, с учетом всех замечаний, код импорта получится таким

```
typedef int (__fastcall *myFunc)(wchar_t * param1, wchar_t * param2, wchar_t * &param3);
```

или таким

```
typedef int (__fastcall *myFunc)(wchar_t * param1, wchar_t * param2, wchar_t ** param3);
```

Comment: `для платформы Win64 - это единственно возможное соглашение.` А можно ссылку на что-нибудь разжевывающее? Все время считал, что WinAPI использует stdcall вне зависимости от 32/64.

Comment: @kami https://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/94340/

Comment: Моя вина - не дал полную информацию. У функций на Delphi  прописан stdcall. Платформа Win64, функции работают.
Написаны на относительно свежем Delphi, то бишь PChar и string уже в юникоде. 
Вопрос я, кстати, решил иным способом. Но не отписался в силу лени и занятости. 
А именно, используя тип BSTR (класс _b_str)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms221069.aspx
Как-то так:  typedef int (WINAPI *myFunc)(PCHAR, PCHAR, BSTR&);
Данный тип легко преобразуется во все другие строковые типы, главное, не забывать чистить ручками.Не знаю, насколько грамотное решение, но работает.